# JNIEXPORT and JNICALL in Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

While working with some sources written in C++ I found those macro:

JNIEXPORT return_type JNICALL function_name(...) {
However, Android NDK samples don't use them. I read some docs from Oracle, but I'm still confused.

Do I necessarily have to use them while working with Android NDK?

One of the reasons for asking - those macro break syntax highlighting in eclipse CDT :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically is a windows issue, if you have a look to the file jni_md_win32.h that comes with oracle Java jdk this is the macro definition:

```
/*
 * @(#)jni_md.h 1.14 03/12/19
 *
 * Copyright 2004 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * SUN PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
 */

#ifndef _JAVASOFT_JNI_MD_H_
#define _JAVASOFT_JNI_MD_H_

#define JNIEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define JNIIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#define JNICALL __stdcall

typedef long jint;
typedef __int64 jlong;
typedef signed char jbyte;

#endif /* !_JAVASOFT_JNI_MD_H_ */
```

In the header jni_md_linux.h those macros are empty. So I guess that as long you don't want your native code to be executed in windows with oracle JVM you can remove those macros.

Comment: And a Linux issue: `#define JNIEXPORT  __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))`. Its probably used with `-fvisibility=hidden` to keep the size of the export table down. Reducing the export symbol table size decreases shared object load time and binary size. See [Visibility - GCC Wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility).

Answer (score 1):

Check that the include path of the platform you desire from the Android NDK has been added to your project's C\C++ includes. This can be done as follows:

- Open the project properties
- Expand C/C++ General
- Click Paths and Symbols
- In the Includes section Add the path to the includes folder of the desired platform of the NDK (e.g. ${ANDROID_NDK_HOME}\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include )